# Show email To: and CC's in message body in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

This is how an email looks that I receive.

[image: email that I receive]
<sup>(*From, Date, Subject, To* in the message)</sup>

This is how an email looks that I send.

[image: email looks that I send]
<sup>(only says *On ... I wrote*, etc.)</sup>

How can I make it so my messages are like that?

Comment: You're comparing a _forwarded_ message and a _replied_ message – they're going to have different formats because they have different purposes. Are you trying to make the "Reply" quote format more verbose?

Comment: This happens to any email, not only forwarded mails. I'm trying to make all the reply's I send to be the same as the screenshot from the forwarded message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom headers with the [Change quote and reply format](https://freeshell.de/%7Ekaosmos/changequote-en.html) add-on. Add To: %%8 CC: %%9 as a 'Customized reply header' in the add-ons Options.

To Install, drag the Download link at the bottom of the page and drop it onto Tools/Add-ons in TB.

*source: [Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1188567)*

Comment: Thank you, after testing your response i found it was not compatible with the latest thunderbird version. However on this link https://www.systutorials.com/3165/outlook-style-email-reply-header-thunderbird/ i found the solution. Much appreciated